# CodeIgniter Form validation is not working on Ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I just learned to use form in CodeIgniter. I had learn it before, but run on Windows. And now, I'm trying on Ubuntu. I had followed user_guide, but when I was running it, there was no change on the page.

Here are the view named myform.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

    <?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

    <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
</body>
```

the other form named formsuccess.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Your form was active!</h3>
    <p><?php echo anchor('form', 'Try it again!'); ?></p>
</body>
```

here are the controller named form.php

```
 function index() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('myform');
    } else {
        print_r('good luck!');
    }
}
```

when I click on submit button, it still show myform.php means the form is not working. Can you see the problem? Is there any difference between running CodeIgniter on Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you using HMVC extension?

Comment: have you defined any validation rules?  Also is your form using POST or GET? form_validation only works with POST.

Comment: Ya, I'm using HMVC, Damien.

Comment: No, I haven't defined any validation rules, Ragga. Because, I wanna make sure that form_validation is working first. Then, I'll add other rules. Any idea? Where can I put method on  <?php echo form_open('form'); ?> ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the stupid question. Because there is a note on user guide that I wasn't see. "If you submit the form you should simply see the form reload. That's because you haven't set up any validation rules yet."

Comment: Yes without validation rules the form_validation->run() will return False... as there are no validation rules to check against.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the stupid question. Because there is a note on user guide that I wasn't see. "If you submit the form you should simply see the form reload. That's because you haven't set up any validation rules yet."